# converting java code to objective c

Tags: java, objective-c, hash, converters, md5

at the moment i got an assignment for convert a string into md5 using objective C,

i already tested several code but the result is always different with the server result

(server and mobile convert the string into md5 and then we compare the result to know if it the same to procceed)

here is the code from the server

```
def ii = (userDetailsInstance.imei ?: "") + (userDetailsInstance.devideId ?: "") + (userDetailsInstance.imsi ?: "")
        def digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
        digest.update(ii.getBytes());
        def messageDigest = digest.digest();

        def hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
            hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
```

and this is mine,,

```
- (NSString *)md5 {

    const char * pointer = [self UTF8String];
    unsigned char md5Buffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_MD5(pointer, (CC_LONG)strlen(pointer), md5Buffer);

    NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [string appendFormat:@"%02x",md5Buffer[i]];

    return string;
}
```

the result is very similar

- md5 result from server : b43ad0be803f612a9c3f6a6bc974434
- md5 result from mycode : b43ad0be803f612a9c3f6a6bc9744304
- both result came from this string : 1A963D37-14D1-4725-8515-FBFB494D02AB

so i think this is not a pure md5 but there is slight modifications, im not really good with java, so anyone here can help me?

i already try j2objc but i cant get the converted code.

regards.

Comment: No modifications, your Java code just is wrong when outputting values 0-15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Objective-C code uses the format `%02X` so bytes are converted with a leading zero when required. Your Java code uses `toHexString` which does not zero-pad to 2 hex digits, so no leading zeroes.

The last byte of your result is the only one where the upper four bits are zero, so you get the single difference.

Comment: is there any suggestion for my code to follow the java code?
since i believe that is on purpose.

Comment: I would say the Java is wrong, but if you want to mimic it just change your format. You specified `%02X`, i.e. zero-padded minimum 2 digit hex, use something else. E.g. for values <= 15 just use `%X`, or using masking, your choice.

Comment: Thank you very much, i just a newbie in this office,, i already stat that the server code (java) is wrong, but since im the new guy, they just ask me if i can make the same with the convert.